# Canvas improperly overlaying a TextBlock component inside a DockPanel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, canvas, viewbox

[image]

In the image here, each block with a number in it represents a laser.  These blocks are laid out on a canvas inside a DockPanel.  Also inside the DockPanel docked to the top is the red TextBlock that you can see is hiding behind the laser map canvas.  Why is this happening?  The TextBlock is docked to the top of the DockPanel and canvas has no dock setting, therefore it should fill the rest of space.  Also of note: I had to put the DockPanel inside a ViewBox in order for the whole center screen space to scale properly on window resizes.  Then I had to put that ViewBox inside a ScrollViewer to allow scroll bars to appear when needed.

Here is the XAML Code for the center screen (Note: Child of the Window is a DockPanel.  Menu is docked to the top, left-hand button panel is docked to the left, right-hand button panel is docked to the right, the status bar is docked to the bottom and everything you see in the center screen is defined by the following XAML code)

```
    <ScrollViewer
        Name="centerScreenScrollViewer"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{Binding IsScrollbarsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToScrollbarVisConverter}, FallbackValue=Hidden}">
        <Viewbox>
            <DockPanel
                LastChildFill="True">
                <TextBlock
                    DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                    Name="tbkFullVisual"
                    Style="{StaticResource tbkStyleBlue}"
                    Foreground="Red"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding FullVisual}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    FontSize="24">
                    *** This Print Requires Full Visual Inspection! ***
                </TextBlock>
                <Canvas x:Name="mapCanvas">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MapCanvas}"/>
                </Canvas>
            </DockPanel>
        </Viewbox>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Any help in solving this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Kyle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with the way that a `ViewBox` works, in particular with the `Canvas` element.  The `ViewBox` is used to resize child elements, as I'm sure you're aware.  There are 2 issues with the `Canvas` element:

1. The default `Height` and `Width` are 0, which means that the `TextBlock` will get all the space.
2. The `Canvas` element lets you draw outside of its own boundaries, so even if your canvas is tiny or not even visible, you would be allowed to render your grid of numbers.

The quickest solution is to set `VerticalAlignment` on the `ViewBox`:

```
<Viewbox VerticalAlignment="Top">
    ...
</Viewbox>
```

You could set a `Height` on the Canvas, but I think this is less ideal because you don't want to change this dynamically with window resize.

Comment: This works well.  Thanks, I will accept this answer.  But first, one other quick question for you:  How can I make it so the canvas children will not go outside its bounds?  I have used ClipToBounds=True, but that screws things up since I don't have a defined size for the canvas.  Any suggestions?  The only thing I could think of doing is to override OnWindowResize.  In there, set the height and width of the canvas to the viewport height and viewport width of the viewbox.

Comment: I would reconsider using a `ViewBox` and instead just have the `DockPanel`.  The main purpose of the `ViewBox` is to maintain aspect ratio and scaling when resizing, from what I understand; in this case you want a canvas to automatically fill available space, which the `ViewBox` will prevent.  You could consider trying to bind the `Width` of the Canvas to the `Width` of the ViewBox, then bind the `Height` as well but use a converter to subtract the height of the `TextBlock`; this is really ugly, though.  @kformeck